# Calculating Cartesian product of matrix

Tags: graph-theory

I don't know why I'm struggling to work this out.

I'm reading a paper on Algebraic Graph theory and come up with this problem.

$x_{i} \in \Re^{d}, i = 1, ....., N$. Let $V = {1, ......, N}$

Where Edge set is $E \subset V x V$. Where the interpretation is that an edge $(v_{i}, v_{j})$ is in E if agents $i$ and $j$ can interact with each other.

So is the following true:

Let $V = [1, 0, 1, 0]$

Then $V x V = [(1, 0), 
               (1, 1),  
               (0, 0),
               (0, 1)]$

Or do I need to create two series for $i$ and then for $V$ because the way that I got taught set theory was that in order to calculate the Cartesian product, two data-series must be given.

Hope someone can help me